# Test query execution time in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpunit

How to test in laravel/phpunit how long query took to execute?

Is it possible so that it does not depend on something else?

Comment: Enable the database logging in your database config file, and it tells you in the log for every individual query that's executed

Answer (score 42):

The oldest way is the best one:

```
$start = microtime(true);
// Execute the query
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
```

Comment: As a sidenote, in traditinal unit testing, you should never ever touch your database. Unit testing is for testing small, stateless functionality. A database is all about saving state, so test your database in integration tests.

Answer (score 7):

Since Laravel 5.2 `listen` has changed to only accept one argument:

```
\DB::listen(function ($query) {
     // $query->sql
     // $query->bindings
     // $query->time
});
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database

Answer (score 6):

That's how I did it in laravel 9x.

Open `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` put code snippet below inside `boot method`:

```
DB::listen(function ($query) {
    Log::info($query->sql);     // the query being executed
    Log::info($query->time);    // query time in milliseconds
});
```

Then check the log file for the details in `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Answer (score 2):

You could `listen` to executing query like this and log the result in `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

```
\DB::listen(function ($sql, $bindings, $time) {
    \Log::info($sql, $bindings, $time);
});
```

You could just use `$time` only, but I logged `$sql, $bindings, $time` for the completion.

You could put this inside your `AppServiceProvider`.

**UPDATE:**

In Laravel version > 5.5 this approach is documented in the doc as [listening for query events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#listening-for-query-events) ;)

Comment: Anyone happen to know the unit of the `$time` variable in the Laravel query logs?

Comment: The comment in the source indicates that it's milliseconds. This seems to be the case from my testing. https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/ad4000cadedcaeb76c28874d1f3425d7bf1f7f8a/Events/QueryExecuted.php#L22

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ddd($someVar)` helper starting from Laravel 6.x.

There is `Queries` tab which describes each query executed until `ddd()`