# Nginx POST requests are slow

Tags: laravel, nginx

For some reason all the POST request are delayed for about 1 min. Here is my confuguration:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay off;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
client_max_body_size 0;
send_timeout 300;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;

location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 60
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 20
pm.max_spare_servers = 60
```

Comment: We might need some more information in order to help. Like this POST request you are doing is on an application you developed? What is supposed to be doing?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Laravel as back-end. The POST request is just a CRUD operation, in this case,  creates a new record in the data base

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aiming for the accepted answer, but I'll try to give some advices.

1. Be sure you don't have `xgebug` enabled.
2. Use `LARAVEL_START` to check your execution time during requests. You can use something like this `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::debug(microtime(true)-LARAVEL_START);`. Put it somewhere in your code, so you can find out the most heavy parts. For example, at the top of your CRUD method and at the end of it.
3. Check other processes are running on your server. Probably there is something CPU/RAM consuming.
4. `systemctl nginx reload` sometimes works :)
5. You can [listen to your DB queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48938845/9506712), probably some of them are too slow.